# PHP reorder array with starting index

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of days in week. I want to re-order array by giving starting day.

```
$days_order = array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun");
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($days_order); 
echo '</pre>';
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Mon
    [1] => Tue
    [2] => Wed
    [3] => Thu
    [4] => Fri
    [5] => Sat
    [6] => Sun
)
```

**Question:** How to re-order array when set starting day?

*Note: Index values are important.*

Example:

If I set **starting day** to `"Wed"`, then array will output this:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Wed
        [1] => Thu
        [2] => Fri
        [3] => Sat
        [4] => Sun
        [5] => Mon
        [6] => Tue
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to have an array of dates pre-defined, just loop through date().

```
$start_date = 'Wed';

for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++) $arr[$i] = date('D', strtotime("Next $start_date +$i days"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (($i = array_search('Wed', $days_order)) !== false)
    $result = array_merge(array_slice($days_order, $i), array_slice($days_order, 0, $i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$days_order = array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun");
$split_by = array_search("Wed", $days_order);

if ($split_by) {
    $first = array_slice($days_order, 0, $split_by);
    $second = array_slice($days_order, $split_by);
$result = array_merge($second, $first);
}
    print_r($result);
```

Comment: Your answer is a total duplicate of my one